# Can I force PDF documents in my web application to get opened by Adobe Acrobat plugin

Tags: pdf, model-view-controller, webforms, acrobat, livecycle-designer

Is it possible somehow to force my pdf documents to open always with the Adobe plugin for opening pdf's in a browser?

The problem is that I have some forms that have to be filled and saved(made with Adobe LiveCycle Designer) but with the Chrome PDF Viewer or others different than Adobe's it fails and the filled pdf can not be saved or saves but without the entered data.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot force pdf to be viewed by acrobat by default. Default pdf applications set by browser will be there. You need to go through browsers in order to change the plugin. No code can invoke this functio